How do I run a vba code every time a cell in a specific row changes?
I currently have a vba code that copies data from one worksheet to a number of new worksheets depending on the option chosen from a drop down list in column D.
I need this code to run everytime the drop down list is used on ever row.
This is the vba code that is currently working
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sub FilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet, InactiveSheet As Worksheet, PendingSheet As Worksheet,     RenewedSheet As Worksheet, FollowUpSheet As Worksheet, RedZoneSheet As Worksheet

Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Active")
Set InactiveSheet = Sheets("Inactive")
Set PendingSheet = Sheets("Pending")
Set RenewedSheet = Sheets("Renewed")
Set FollowUpSheet = Sheets("Follow Up")
Set RedZoneSheet = Sheets("Red Zone")

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With Range("A1", "R" & lngLastRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Active"
    .Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Inactive"
    .Copy InactiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Pending"
    .Copy PendingSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Renewed"
    .Copy RenewedSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Follow Up"
    .Copy FollowUpSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Red Zone"
    .Copy RedZoneSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Everytime I change any cell in column D the data doesnt copy automatically. I need to manually go to developer, open visual basic and the run the module before the data will copy to the new worksheet.

The Worksheet.SelectionChange event fires when the Selection changes — i.e. when you Select a different cell/object (and Target will be the Newly-Selected Cell/Object).  Did you mean to use the Worksheet.Change event, to fire when the value of the cell changes (and Target will be the Cell that changed)?

Im not sure which event is required. If D2 = active then row 2 will copy to a new worksheet called active but if i change D2 to inactive I need row 2 to copy to a worksheet called inactive and remove from the previous worksheet called active and I need this change to happen everytime column D is changed on every row

To check when the value of a cell has changed, you will trigger the Worksheet.Change event, not the Worksheet.SelectionChange event.
Then, you want to use that to check if the cell that has changed is in Column D — and, if it is, then you can run whatever code you wanted to.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim colD As Range, rngChange As Range
    
    Set colD = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(4)) 'Get the list of Values in Column D that have changed
    
    If Not (colD Is Nothing) Then
        'A Value in Column D has been changed!  We need to do something…
        
        '''SAMPLE CODE START'''
        For Each rngChange In colD.Cells
            If rngChange.Value = "Active" Then
                MakeRowActive rngChange.EntireRow
            ElseIf rngChange.Value = "Inactive" Then
                MakeRowInActive rngChange.EntireRow
            End If
        Next rngChange
        '''SAMPLE CODE END'''
    End If
End Sub

Replace the SAMPLE CODE with whatever you need to happen when a value in Column D has been changed.
